# Best Scenario to handle nested forms in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i have web application where include invoice. I want to ask what is the best scenario to handle nested forms in rails to be simple for user.

Answer (score 0):

The best scenario for nested_form would be

1. One to one relationship.
2. One to many relationship.

In the above when you want to created both the parent and the child records at the same time
eg.
**Profile** has many **ProfileImages** and while creating profile we want to upload image. So the **Profile** form would be `nested_form` and the **ProfileImage** field_for would we inside the **Profile** form.

And with nested form you can also insert multiple records of the child with one nested_form